# Prevent EOL normalization for CSV files

Tags: git, github, eol, end-of-line

I have a source repository that is used both from **Windows** and **Linux**.

I know that **Git** will automatically convert **EOL** to the local standard: **\r\n** on Windows and **\n** on Linux.

This is not an issue for source files.

But I have some **CSV files** that use a fixed format with a given EOL character (**\r\n**) which should not be changed, but Git converts them too, breaking some code.

I've tried to prevent EOL conversions for CSV files by creating a **.gitattributes** file at the root, next to the **.gitignore** file, with the following content:

```
*.csv    -text
```

I've applied what I've understood from: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

But Git is still converting **\r\n** to **\n** on Linux.

Should I play with another setting like auto.crlf?

Note that I have limited control of the Linux local repository as it is managed by the **continuous integration server Jenkins**.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: The file extensions on linux are case-sensitive. Are your CSV files actually *.CSV?  Try adding a few case variations to your .gitattributes file.

Comment: Have you tried

    `*.csv eol=crlf`?

Comment: @PaulHicks: thanks but all extensions are "csv" in lower case.

Comment: @AchalDave: thanks for the suggestion but some other CSV files may be formatted with **\n** instead of **\r\n** so I can't apply a uniform conversion policy, I want to disable any conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that git uses LF as an internal representation of EOL.

This means that in your case, the *.csv files has got changed when they were added/committed.

So the solution goes roughly like this:

1. remove all the *.csv files, commit that change
2. edit .gitattributes, commit
3. add back all the *.csv files, commit again

Actually, it can be all made in one commit, with the following commands:

```
### ... update .gitattributes
git rm --cached '*.csv'
### ... find -name '*.csv' -print0| xargs -0 unix2dos
git add '*.csv'
git add .gitattributes
git commit
```

Explanation:

- `git rm --cached` removes all csv files from index, leaving them on the disk;
- ensure the files have CRLF line endings (I'm using `unix2dos` as an example)
- `git add '*.csv'` adds them back, this time without any transformation, according to new version of .gitattributes